# Networking Vlan

Tags: networking

How many Vlan create a particular Switch. If a Switch has 48 prots then we can create 48 Vlan or higher.

Comment: How many horse powers does a car have? If the car has a steering wheel, will that influence the horse powers?

Guess what, like cars.... switches are made by manufacturers. Like cars, the manufacturers of a switch determine what the switch can do.

There no answer that is "correct" here.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to offer a simple answer to an unclear question : You can create more VLANs than the physical number of ports on a switch.